# reformatting dates with square brackets

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, square-bracket

When transferring my XML-files to TeX I try to reformat dates – my publisher said I had to use a smaller horizontal space between dates – and can't manage to go beyond the first step.

My input file is this

```
<a>
<date>January 1900</date>
<date>2. 2. 1902</date>
<date>3. [3]. 1903</date>
<date>[4. 4. 1904]</date>
</a>
```

where brackets mean that the date is not certain. There are all possible combination of brackets, e.g. second number of the year: 1[9]00. I created a command \mini which makes small space in TeX:
\newcommand{\mini}{\,}
The result after the xslt should be:

```
January 1900
2.{\mini}2.{\mini}1902
3.{\mini}[3].{\mini}1903
[4.{\mini}4.{\mini}1904]
```

I wrote a function, which tries to extract the square brackets and store their position to a variable and afterwards concat them back again. But as I don't manage to get the variables to show correct positions, I'm stuck:

```
<xsl:function name="foo:date-translate">
      <xsl:param name="date-string" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:variable name="opening-square-bracket" as="xs:integer" select="count(substring-before($date-string,'&#91;'))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="closing-square-bracket" as="xs:integer" select="count(substring-before($date-string,'&#x5b;'))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="date-string-without-square-brackets" as="xs:string" select="replace(replace($date-string,'\[',''),'\]','')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches($date-string-without-square-brackets,'\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}. \d{4}')">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($date-string,'['))"> 
               <xsl:value-of select="replace($date-string,'(\d{1,2}). (\d{1,2}). (\d{4})','$1\\mini$2\\mini$3')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> 
               <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(replace($date-string-without-square-brackets,'(\d{1,2}). (\d{1,2}). (\d{4})','$1\\mini$2\\mini$3'),0,$opening-square-bracket),'[',substring(replace($date-string-without-square-brackets,'(\d{1,2}). (\d{1,2}). (\d{4})','$1\\mini$2\\mini$3'),$opening-square-bracket, $closing-square-bracket))"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="$date-string"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:function>
```

Comment: is it at all possible to have proper inputs, i.e. a proper date format. Without that it's going to be error-prone guesswork.

Comment: why don't you just replace any space with the smaller space?

Comment: I have a attribute @when which stores the date in 1900-01-01 format and that could be used. but it doesn't contain the uncertainties.

Comment: @AndrewMagerman : because that would change December 1900 as well but the smaller space should only be between numbers

Comment: I would code around the case which is an exception. Less work

Comment: @AndrewMagerman i have 2000 dates with maybe one fourth with brackets, so I can't really code around it.

Comment: [rylhe]( )\d{2,4} this regex will find all the space characters between an english-language month and a year. I'd replace all the spaces with your mini thingumbobby, except for those spaces found with this regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it with recursion. Basically I have the test whether it suits the regex dd. mm. yyyy when the brackets are removed. as this works i can now rebuild the whole string.

```
<xsl:function name="foo:date-repeat">
      <xsl:param name="date-string" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:param name="amount" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:param name="counter" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="substring($date-string,$counter,1) =' '">
            <xsl:text>\mini</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($date-string,$counter,1)"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:if test="$counter &lt;= $amount">
         <xsl:value-of select="foo:date-repeat($date-string, $amount,$counter+1)"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:function>



 <xsl:function name="foo:date-translate">
      <xsl:param name="date-string" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:variable name="date-string-without-square-brackets" as="xs:string" select="replace(replace($date-string,'\[',''),'\]','')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches($date-string-without-square-brackets,'\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}. \d{4}')">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($date-string,'['))"> <!-- Daten ohne eckige Klammer -->
               <xsl:value-of select="replace($date-string,'(\d{1,2}). (\d{1,2}). (\d{4})','$1\\mini$2\\mini$3')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="foo:date-repeat($date-string, string-length($date-string),1)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="$date-string"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:function>
```

I have even expanded my solution, now the function checks tests every space ' ' if before is a dot or a dot and a bracket and afterwards is a number or a bracket and a number:

```
<xsl:function name="foo:date-repeat">
  <xsl:param name="date-string" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="amount" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="counter" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:choose> 
     <xsl:when test="substring($date-string,$counter,1) =' ' and ((substring($date-string,$counter -1,1) = '.' and number(substring($date-string,$counter -2,1)) = number(substring($date-string,$counter -2,1))) or (substring($date-string,$counter -2,2) = '.]' and number(substring($date-string,$counter -3,1)) = number(substring($date-string,$counter -3,1))))">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="number(substring($date-string,$counter +1,1)) = number(substring($date-string,$counter +1,1))">
              <xsl:text>\mini</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="substring($date-string,$counter +1,1) ='[' and number(substring($date-string,$counter +2,1)) = number(substring($date-string,$counter +2,1))">
              <xsl:text>\mini</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring($date-string,$counter,1)"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="substring($date-string,$counter,1) ='['">
        <xsl:text>{[}</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="substring($date-string,$counter,1) =']'">
        <xsl:text>{]}</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($date-string,$counter,1)"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:if test="$counter &lt;= $amount">
     <xsl:value-of select="foo:date-repeat($date-string, $amount,$counter+1)"/>
  </xsl:if>
```